# SQL job fails to execute package, but VS not

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, sql-agent-job

When I run package directly from Visual Studio then it doesn't throw error. When I execute the package via SQL Server Agent Job then it throws error:

> Source: Fact_Invoice_Item PWBConsolidation [1]     Description: SSIS
>   Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error
>   code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft
>   SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x00040EDA  Description:
>   "Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET
>   operation.".  End Error  Error: 2012-02-14 07:17:49.01     Code:
>   0xC0047038     Source: Fact_Invoice_Item SSIS.Pipeline
>   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput
>   method on component "PWBConsolidation" (1) returned error code
>   0xC0202009.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline
>   engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is
>   defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline
>   stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this
>   with more information about the failure.  End Error  DTExec: The
>   package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  7:14:35 AM 
>   Finished: 7:17:50 AM  Elapsed:  195.094 seconds.  The package
>   execution failed.  NOTE: The step was retried the requested number of
>   times (3) without succeeding.  The step failed.

I have isolated a part that is causing the problem. In Ole Db Source I use query to get the data and when I remove the following line then the package is executed successfully via Sql Server Agent Job:

```
Checksum = Checksum(S.BrokerID, S.TeamID, II.DatabaseName, II.INVOICE, I.Invoice_Date, P.Expiration_Date, P.Effective_Date, 
    P.Binder_Effective, I.AGENCY, II.MARKET, P.POLICY, CT.LINE_OF_BUSINESS, II.Coverage_Type, SUB.INSURED, 
    LOB.Description, CT.Description, I.Date_Due, I.Installment, P.Installments, P.ENDORSES, I.Inv_Tdate, Inv_Acctcur,
    INS.INDUSTRY, SUB.SUBMISSION
    )
```

EDIT:
I have just checked and looks like part of data gets through data flow and at some point it just throws error. I have manually set Checksum=2 and still doesn't work

Any idea why is this so?

Thanks a lot,
Ilija

Comment: I would look at the permissions of the SQL Agent account relative to the referenced tables and columns. It would appear that it does not have select permission on one of those eight or so tables. Are all those columns included in the dataflow? If one's missing, that'd be the most likely candidate for insufficient privileges.

Comment: They are appearing in data flow. What's even worse, this has worked several weeks until today

Comment: Any chance the package protection level is EncryptSensitiveWithUserCredentials and the PackageCreator's Active Directory account was recently removed?

Comment: What's the datatype for the Checksum field? If it's a binary/LOB type, you may be experiencing file system permission issues.

Comment: How can I know what's the datatype? I guess it's someting that's default, right? Can it be changed?

Comment: Add that statement back in and right-click on the dataflow immediately proceeding the Ole Db Source. Select Edit, then view the Metadata tab.

Comment: it's DT_I4. I guess this is 4-byte integer?

Comment: I have tried ProtectionLevel = DontSaveSensitive. Account is not removed from active directory.

Comment: Could you update the ticket with a screen shot of the data flow? Also, what is PWBConsolidation? Is that a destination, transformation, source?

Comment: For some reason today there is no this error. I have no clue what happened. If error appears again I will update my question

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are running into a constraint issue on your table that you are inserting into or values you are operating on...like aggregate function(max,sum,avg..) exists on a null value.

Try redirecting error rows to a flat file or something of that nature and see if you still get the error.

Also try set ANSI_WARNINGS OFF in your SQL statement

Enjoy and good luck

Comment: "Try redirecting error rows to a flat file or something of that nature and see if you still get the error." - Which error rows? Those that can't be inserted to destination?